# Display serialized column data in laravel backpack show view

Tags: laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

I want to display serialized data from database in a laravel backpack show view. The data is stored like this: { father:'value', mother: 'value'.etc}

The goal is to unserialize it and display it in different input field...

The laravel backback documentation don't cover a scenario like this one.

the goal is to unserialized the serilzed data and display it in different uneditable input fields

Answer (score 0):

if the `json` column ( https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-columns#json-1 ) is not what you are looking for, I would advise to create a custom column to display in your show view: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-columns#creating-a-custom-column-type-1

Cheers

Comment: I get the following error when I use the json column:

Cannot find the field view: json. Please check for typos. If you are trying to use a PRO field, please first purchase and install the backpack/pro addon from backpackforlaravel.com